# Xampp, how do I get to phpmyadmin when my htdocs are in dropbox?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp, dropbox, synchronization

I was searching for a way to sync all my xampp prodject between different computers and find a guide that showed how to sync it with dropbox.

But now to the problem, when I write "localhost/phpadmin" in my brower so normaly I get to the phpadmin page but I don't. I guess it searches for a map in the htdocs and find nothing.

Iam woundering if there is anyone out there that also uses dropbox and have find a way to get to the phpadmin page. I really need to get there to configer stuff and edit my database.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you changed some paths, while changing you htdocs directory to point to the dropbox folder.

In XAMPP (1.8.3 - can't check other versions right now), there is an alias defined for phpmyadmin. You can find it at

```
[yourXAMPPdirectory]/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

There should be something like this:

```
<IfModule alias_module>

  <!-- some other stuff -->

    Alias /phpmyadmin "[yourXAMPPdirectory]/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "[yourXAMPPdirectory]/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

  <!-- some other stuff -->


</IfModule>
```

Make sure this points to the correct folder of phpmyadmin.

---

Another solution would be to just install a new phpMyAdmin instance to the dropbox folder and use that one. You would have to configure the auth properly, so you can enter the respective credentials for each machine.

Comment: @JoakimJohansson If this solved your problem, consider accepting the answer, in order to show others, that this has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I relized that I was trying to go to localhost/phpadmin but the correct link is localhost/phpmyadmin xD
After trying that link, everything worked, sorry for taking you time but thank you for helping :)

Joakim